# Gnome 3.14 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, gnome, ubuntu-gnome

Can i get Gnome 3.14 on Ubuntu 12.04? I saw this people have mentioned 12.04 in the list for gnome 3.14

http://media-opensource.blogspot.com/2014/09/how-to-install-gnome-314-in-linux.html

Comment: Wouldn't recommend you to do it, if you don't know what you are doing. Why do you want gnome 3.14 would be a point to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the PPA as a test. But I think that there are no more packages for Ubuntu 12.04. I do not see any more [here](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3-staging).

Comment: oh, yeah i've seen it. So it's a no go right?

Comment: I think so, but you can test it.
Add the PPA and try a `sudo apt-get update`. If errors occur, then it is not. Then you can remove the PPA.

Comment: I think i'd better not. Can't afford to mess up my Ubuntu. Don't even have a system image. Thank you @A.B.